# SEO meta - Multiple fallback options?

Tags: templates, seo, seo-lite

I've looked at SEO Lite and NSM Better Meta.

These SEO addons come with 1 default fallback template. By "fallback" I am referring to fallback meta data that displays if there is no title, description, or keyword values saved to the entry.

I need to be able to have different fallback SEO meta on a per section basis if no SEO meta is entered for an entry. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen my blog post on [SEO & ExpressionEngine](http://caffeinecreations.ca/blog/seo-and-expressionengine). I'm sure using that approach would get you partway to what you want to do.

Additionally I would take a look at SurgEEo - which I believe addresses some of what I was trying to do in the blog post linked above. I'm going to be trying out [SurgEEo](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/surgeeo) on my next build so can't guarantee this yet.

Comment: Think I'll give SurgEEo a try. The SEO agency will probably want to edit the meta for certain sections that don't contain entries i.e. category landing page. Too often the SEO solutions in my experience turn into a conditional mess. Let's see how this works out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SEO Lite has tag parameters that allow you to override the default meta data directly within the template. So you can do something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries limit='1'}
    {if channel_short_name == 'blog'}
        {exp:seo_lite 
            entry_id='{entry_id}'
            default_title='Blog'
            default_description='The bestest blog in the whole wide world.'
            default_keywords='blog, posts, stuff, junk, things'
        }
    {/if}
    {if channel_short_name == 'contact'}
        {exp:seo_lite 
            entry_id='{entry_id}'
            default_title='Contact'
            default_description='Contact us because we are awesome.'
            default_keywords='contact, email, form, notify'
        }
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

There's [a similar example in the docs](http://wedoaddons.com/addon/seo-lite/documentation#the-ultimate-setup) that uses embedded template variables.